# Kubuntu 16.04 Application launcher is only working on virtual desktop 1

Tags: kubuntu, launcher

I'm a relative noob. The application launcher WAS working fine on all 4 virtual desktops I'm using, but apparently I did something and now it only works on virtual desktop 1.  It's still there on all 4 desktops, but clicking on it on any other desktop but 1 does nothing.  You have to go to virtual desktop 1 to launch any application.  It's probably something simple, but I just can't seem to find what's causing this problem. Any help would be appreciated.

Thanks!

Update...edit doesn't seem to save my previous comments.  I found clicking on the Application Launcher on any desktop other than 1 does not open it on that desktop, but it does open it on desktop 1.  That means you have to go to desktop 1 to open another app.
[image]
[image]

Comment: Screenshot / screen recording please.

Comment: I've made a screen recording, but I'm not sure how to post it here.

Comment: Second update.  I just discovered that when attempting to open an all history window from Firefox on desktop 4, it does open the window, but opens it on desktop 1.  I'm thinking that and the application launcher issue are related.  It seems to be a desktop setting, but I can't seem to figure out which one would cause this behavior.

Comment: Third update.  I've tried defaulting every setting having anything remotely to do with the desktop.  No luck.  It does appear to either be a bad setting or possibly a corrupt desktop configuration file.  I tried a fresh install, formatting the root partition, but left the /home partition and again, there was no change which tells me it has something to do with a file under my user.  I will create another user and log in as that to see if I'm still having that problem as a different user.

Comment: 4th update.  I didn't have a user manager in the application launcher and it took some time to find an answer for that.  Added gnome-system-tools and the user manager was there.  Added another user, logged in as that user and everything works as it should.  Applications launched on a virtual desktop open on that desktop instead of desktop 1 as it does on my profile.  So this issue seems to be some problem with my user profile.  Is there a way to default the user profile without deleting and rebuilding it?